# How to change unit of list that was read from a text file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to change the unit of a value in a text file. First part of the task was to turn the string list to a float, but now (without using index()) I want to change the unit of the elemets which are kbps to mbps, so the 1200 value to 1.2.

This is the code that turns the values of the list to float:

```
bw  = [] #another comment: create an empty list
with open("task4.txt") as file_name:
    for line in file_name:
        a = line.split() #The split() method splits a string into a list - whitspace as a default
        bw.append(a[0]) #only appending the first value
        floats = [float(line) for line in bw] #Turnes the string into a float

print(bw)
```

The text file looks like this:

```
7 Mbps
1200 Kbps
15 Mbps
32 Mbps
```

I need the list to become 7, 1.2, 15, 32 without changing the textfile, nor use index. I want a programs that finds all kbps values and turns them into mbps

Comment: You need the list to change without changing the file? Are you writing the results to a new file, or do you just need to convert the values in the list "floats"?

Comment: I need to read the throughput values from the file into a list, but the values must use the same units (mbps). The float is because im gonna use the list later in a formula, so they cant be string

Comment: basically, read the throughput values from the file, somehow turn all kbps values into mbps values, to later use in a formula. I should be able to add more elements to the list and move the kbps value without changing the code

Comment: `a[1]` contains the unit of value `a[0]`. Convert the value to float, check if unit is "Kbps" and if so, divide value by 1000. Finally append value to `bw`.

Answer (score 2):

You have to check the first letter of the units to determine whether to divide by 1000 to convert Kpbs to Mbps.

```
bw  = [] #another comment: create an empty list
with open("task4.txt") as file_name:
    for line in file_name:
        speed, unit = line.split()
        speed = float(speed)
        if unit.startswith('K'):
            speed /= 1000
        bw.append(speed)
print(bw)
```

Comment: it worked on the kbps one, but i lost the 7:((

Comment: I suspect you have an indentation problem, and `bw.append(speed)` is inside the `if`.

Comment: sorry, my mistake, it worked!

Answer (score 0):

If you want both the Mbps and Kbps in the list you could try my code below:

```
with open('task4.txt', 'r') as file:
    sizes = []
    for line in file:
        size, unit = line.strip().split()
        if unit == 'Mbps':
            sizes.append(float(size))
        else:
            sizes.append(float(size)/1000)

print(sizes)
```

Comment: You should explain what your code does.

Answer (score 0):

To start, you can open and parse the file into a `list` by line:

```py
speeds = []
with open("task4.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    speeds = file.read().splitlines()
```

After reading the file, the task becomes a one-liner.

```py
speeds = [str(int(x.split()[0]) / 1000) + " " + x.split()[1] if "kbps" in x.lower() else x for x in speeds]
```

For readability's sake, I have included a more verbose solution with comments here, although it does the exact same thing as the above:

```py
# Create a temporary array to hold the converted speeds
new_speeds = []
# For each speed in the list
for speed in speeds:
    # If the speed is in Kbps
    if "kbps" in speed.lower():
        # Fetch the raw speed integer and the unit name from the string
        n_kbps, unit = speed.split()
        # Convert the raw speed integer to Mbps
        n_kbps /= 100
        # Add the converted speed to the new_speeds array
        new_speeds.append(f"{n_kbps} {unit}")
    # If the speed is not in Kbps
    else:
        # Simply add the existing speed to the new_speeds array
        new_speeds.append(speed)
# Set the original speeds array to the resulting array
speeds = new_speeds
```

Comment: There's no need for `speeds` (haha, [get it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CUpwLhZh66A)?) to be read first. You could skip that and just do `for x in speeds` in your loop and strip each line